# OSError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x02F41960> while trying to reuse downloaded header

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, python-requests, python-imaging-library

My project is in Python 3.6.2. I'm trying to identify whether images are worth downloading at all (if they have a certain aspect ratio) by reading only the header (first ~100 bytes of the online file), so far just testing with imghdr and Pillow.

Image.open fails at the end with:

> File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2349, in open
>       % (filename if filename else fp))
>
> OSError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x02F41960>

I found [Release notes 2.8.0 for Pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.2.x/releasenotes/2.8.0.html?highlight=stream) which seemed to suggest I'd be able to use Image.open(requests.raw). I guessed I should be able to reuse the already-downloaded header after ensuring I reset it with seek(0).

Other answers with this error seem to deal with saving the image buffer to an actual file, **which I am trying to avoid** (just reusing the downloaded bytes from response.raw for all my test/checks, and not making multiple download requests to any server.)

Where am I going wrong please?

Here is my sample code:

```
import requests
from PIL import Image
import imghdr
import io

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = "https://ichef-1.bbci.co.uk/news/660/cpsprodpb/37B5/production/_89716241_thinkstockphotos-523060154.jpg"
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            response.raw.decode_content = True

            # Grab first 100 bytes as potential image header
            header = response.raw.read(100)
            ext = imghdr.what(None, h=header)
            print("Found: " + ext)
            if ext != None:     # Proceed to other tests if we received an image at all
                header = io.BytesIO(header)
                header.seek(0)
                im = Image.open(header)
                im.verify()

                # other image-related tasks here
        else:
            print("Received error " + str(response.status.code))
    except requests.ConnectionError as e:
        print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the rest of the image data before calling `Image.open()`.

This is what I mean:

```
import requests
from PIL import Image
import imghdr
import io

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = "https://ichef-1.bbci.co.uk/news/660/cpsprodpb/37B5/production/_89716241_thinkstockphotos-523060154.jpg"
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            response.raw.decode_content = True

            # Grab first 100 bytes as potential image header
            header = response.raw.read(100)
            ext = imghdr.what(None, h=header)
            print("Found: " + ext)
            if ext != None:     # Proceed to other tests if we received an image at all
                data = header + response.raw.read()  # GET THE REST OF THE FILE
                data = io.BytesIO(data)
                im = Image.open(data)
                im.verify()

                # other image-related tasks here
        else:
            print("Received error " + str(response.status.code))
    except requests.ConnectionError as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: Is there any library out there that can work with only image headers? I'm specifically trying to avoid downloading unnecessary data.

Comment: Work in what way? It seems unrealistic to expect `Image.open()`, and especially `Image.verify()`, which verifies the _contents_ of a file, to work with one only partially read. Using `BytesIO` does avoid saving the image data to an actual file.

Comment: FYI: As for the `# other image-related tasks`, note also the documentation for [`Image.verify`](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.2.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.verify) says "If you need to load the image after using this method, you must reopen the image file."

Comment: I mean: what image-processing library (if any) would allow me to work with the contents of image headers only (as the info I need at first is contained in headers), and doesn't require complete files? I was actually expecting Pillow to be able to handle headers only as it seems more efficient to avoid downloading entire images when unnecessary, but perhaps that isn't the library I should have chosen.

Comment: You're making an overly broad assumption that the "header" information is always at the beginning of the file. I know of image file formats where it is physically located at the _end_ of the file.

Comment: I'm mostly interested in popular online image formats for now; jpg, gif and png are at the beginning of the file.

Comment: I know of no such library. Time for you to write one!

Comment: Thanks for the discussion, looks like that'll be a part of my project too :)